# Python: how to get the prefer subtext from a text?

Tags: python

I have a text`text = {"data":{"val":"184,190|188,309","id":41299230483},"result":true}`

I just want to get `184,190|188,309`

how should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your value is a `JSON` string, so you need to decode it first before attempting to extract values:

```
import json

text = '{"data":{"val":"184,190|188,309","id":41299230483},"result":true}'

d = json.loads(text)
print(d['data']['val'])
```

Output:

```
184,190|188,309
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
import ast
text = """{"data":{"val":"184,190|188,309","id":41299230483},"result":True}"""
text = ast.literal_eval(text)
yourvalue = text["data"]["val"]
```

Comment: I just tried this, I got the error: "string indices must be integers"

Answer (score 0):

your code has an error. Correct code is `text = {"data":{"val":"184,190|188,309","id":41299230483},"result":True}`

and you can get your output...

```
import json
text= json.loads(text)
print(text["data"]['val'])
```

Comment: the text looks like a whole string type, so I got error  "string indices must be integers"